# Why won't this route match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm having some trouble getting routes to match.

I am using base-32 encoded int's as short links to slideshows in a web app.  There are 5 different versions of each slideshow, and I am using an initial letter to distinguish between each version.

The routes always match, except when the first character of the base-32 encoded int is the same as the character designating the slideshow version.  This anomaly exists for all 5 prefix letters: n, f, c, x, and h.

What about the first two characters being the same makes these routes not match?  I'm at a loss to understand what's going on here (when the routes don't match, they simply fall through to the default).

Route Matches (`/na0`):
[image: route for na0]

Route Doesn't Match (`/nn0`):
[image: route for nn0]

Route Matches (`/nfg`):
[image: route for nfg]

Route Doesn't Match (`/ffg`):
[image: route for ffg]

I'm boggled.  Here's the routing code, in case it isn't clear in the RouteDebug tables in the screenshots:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "NonBrandedSlideshow",
            "n{id}",
            MVC.Slideshow.NonBranded(), null,
            new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "FullSlideshow",
            "f{id}",
            MVC.Slideshow.Full(), null,
            new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CompactSlideshow",
            "c{id}",
            MVC.Slideshow.Compact(), null,
            new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "FlexibleSlideshow",
            "x{id}",
            MVC.Slideshow.Flexible(), null,
            new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Html5Slideshow",
            "h{id}",
            MVC.Slideshow.NonBrandedHtml5(), null,
            new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
        );
```

I should note here that I am using [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC) (see section 2.2.5), and these `MapRoute` methods are extensions added by T4MVC.  The `MapRoute` methods I am using are equivalent to the standard methods, and I have tried using the non-T4MVC `MapRoute` method with the same result:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Html5Slideshow",
            "h{id}",
            new { controller = "Slideshow", action = "NonBrandedHtml5" },
            new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
        );
```

Here is the Base32Regex, though I have tried it with and without this constraint (the Base32 implementation I am using will assume I and O are 1 and 0, for example).

```
public static partial class Settings
{
    public static string Base32Regex
    {
        get { return @"[0-9ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ]+"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Base32 Regex?

Comment: @epignosisx: yes, I did.  It is in the screenshots, but they did not come through at full size it appears.  Note that I had the same result with and without the Regex constraint.

Comment: @qes What tool is that you're using in FireFox for routes??

Comment: @Shark: it's not a FireFox tool, it's Phil Haack's RouteDebugger library: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx

Comment: @mateuscb: ah, thanks for pointing that out.  It's an extension method added by T4MVC.  It's what allows me to use a strongly-typed method to access the action methods - `MVC.Slideshow.Flexible()`.  I have tried the non-T4MVC `MapRoute` and receive the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I am just as boggled. I performed some other tests and as far as I can see, this has to be some bug in the way the routes are checked when the constant before the route parameter has the same repeated character. Some other boggling examples:

```
"nn{id}"
route matches (/nna0)
route doesn't match (/nnn0)

"nnn{id}"
route matches (/nnna0)
route doesn't match (/nnnn0)
```

as soon as i make the constant not repeat the same character, all is well

```
"mn{id}"
route matches (/mna0)
route matches (/mnn0)
route matches (/mnmn)
```

This may not be exactly what you are looking for. But given the oddity of the situation, it was the only thing I could come up with. Add the constant to the constraint and remove it from the url. Then in your controller (this is the part I didn't like) you will need to remove that constant from the id parameter. Hope this works, or at the least help spark another solution.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NonBrandedSlideshow",
    "{id}",
    MVC.Slideshow.NonBranded(), null,
    new { id = "n"+Settings.Base32Regex }
);
```

**UPDATE:**

I guess this is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7476097/461958), thanks @max-toro

Comment: Interesting, I had been looking for confirmation it was a known issue but hadn't found that thread.  a url like `/n8n` works however (in the question Haacked seems to say `_id_` wouldn't work in addition to `__id`.

Comment: The same day I posted this question I already implemented a workaround similar to what you posted because I needed to simply get it working.  However, I didn't think of adding just `n`, etc,  to the constraint - instead I made them all go to the same action and used a switch on the first character to dispatch from there.  I will most likely award you the bounty for that, unless somehow a better answer is posted, which is unlikely since this covers it.

Comment: @qes, it is quite an odd bug. Nice observation about the underline, i really can't quite understand how it is behaving. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in ASP.NET Routing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7476097/39923) for an explication and a workaround. In short, using literal sub-segments does not work very well.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had much success getting routes to match with prefixing a constant to a route parameter like `"const{param}"`. Have you tried using your prefix as a complete route segment, like `"const/{param}"`? Would that meet your requirements?

```
routes.MapRoute(

    "NonBrandedSlideshow",
    "n/{id}",
    MVC.Slideshow.NonBranded(), null,
    new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FullSlideshow",
    "f/{id}",
    MVC.Slideshow.Full(), null,
    new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
);
```

...etc?

**Update after comment #1**

Understood. The only other thing I can think of to try would involve making the id param a catchall parameter. See if that works:

```
routes.MapRoute(

    "NonBrandedSlideshow",
    "n{*id}",
    MVC.Slideshow.NonBranded(), null,
    new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FullSlideshow",
    "f{*id}",
    MVC.Slideshow.Full(), null,
    new { id = Settings.Base32Regex }
);
```

However, these routes should be registered late, so that the controller doesn't end up routing any URL prefixed with n, f, etc. to these controller actions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am constrained on the requirement.  This system has been in production for a good while and it is not feasible to change the url structure for these slideshows as they are already widely distributed.

If it comes to it, I should be able implement a workaround by routing all of these to the same controller action by using one route (without the prefix) and just using logic in the action to check the string.  

However, I would much prefer to find a solution at the routing level.

Comment: re: update - ArgumentException: "A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter." Doesn't look like that will work.

Comment: Ok. I will leave the answer up as an example of what doesn't work to solve this. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried matching them without the route contraint on the end?

EDIT: sorry for half an answer got interrupted

you need to try this for a route constraint

```
     routes.MapRoute(
            "NSlideshow",
            "{id}",
            new { controller = "SlideShow", action = "N", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new
            {
                id = @"^[n]{1}[0-9ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ]+"
            }
        );

     routes.MapRoute(
            "GSlideshow",
            "{id}",
            new { controller = "SlideShow", action = "G", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new
            {
                id = @"^[g]{1}[0-9ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ]+"
            }
        );
```

rinse and repeat for each case, in your action method strip the first character off the front of the id

Comment: I have tried, they do not match. (this would maybe be more appropriate as a comment than an answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround. A weird one, I think...

As you routing rules are pretty simple, you can create a custom `ControllerFactory` and check the url. if the url matches your way, you can define which controller and action to use, and set the id paramenter based on the url. If not, just leave the regular behavior.

I know, it won't make use of the out-of-the-box routing, but as it doesn't work... The good news is as soon as it's fixed you can update the routes, remove the custom ControllerFactory and continue without the workaround.