# MVC4 Can't find the right routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to route following URLs to a controller:

1. /de/flight-london
2. /de/flight-st-petersburg

What is the right URL-Mapping-String to define in Global.asax?

I have tried:

1. "{countrycode}/{keyword}-{destination}" -> good for 1 but not for 2
2. "{countrycode}/{keyword}-{*destination}" -> Exception !

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

`/de/flight-st-petersburg` doesn't work because of a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318373). You have 2 options:

1. Separate keyword and destination with a slash: `{countrycode}/{keyword}/{destination}`
2. Use a model binder, like this:

.

```
class CustomIdentifier {

   public const string Pattern = @"(.+?)-(.+)";
   static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex(Pattern);

   public string Keyword { get; private set; }
   public string Value { get; private set; }

   public static CustomIdentifier Parse(string identifier) {

      if (identifier == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("identifier");

      Match match = Regex.Match(identifier);

      if (!match.Success)
         throw new ArgumentException("identifier is invalid.", "identifier");

      return new CustomIdentifier {
         Keyword = match.Groups[1].Value,
         Value = match.Groups[2].Value
      };
   }
}

class CustomIdentifierModelBinder : IModelBinder {

   public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
      return CustomIdentifier.Parse(
         (string)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).RawValue
      );
   }
}
```

And you register it on Application_Start:

```
void RegisterModelBinders(ModelBinderDictionary binders) {
   binders.Add(typeof(CustomIdentifier), new CustomIdentifierModelBinder());
}
```

Use the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{countryCode}/{id}",
   new { },
   new { id = CustomIdentifier.Pattern });
```

And your action:

```
public ActionResult Flight(CustomIdentifier id) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The route parts are separated by slashes and so you would need to use that I believe:

```
{countrycode}/{keyword}/{*destination}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thx for you answer but our seo experts like to have this url schema: /de/flight-st-petersburg.

Your routing would match only /de/flight/st-peterburg 8(

Comment: As mentioned in Haack's post that Max Toro mentions you could do something like he is recommending with the route constraint. Keep the pattern I put and then have a route constraint that requires the destination to begin with a dash (or the keyword).

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry but I don't understand your idea. Can you please be more clear?